# Where Can The Fully Diluted Outstanding Shares Of A Company Be Found?

Tags: stocks, shares, corporation

This is a quick question.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shares_outstanding) mentions the distinction between basic shares outstanding and "fully diluted shares outstanding".  Does anyone know where I can find the count for fully diluted shares outstanding for a particular company traded on the NASDAQ?  I noticed that sometimes the number of outstanding shares for a company vary considerably between different 3rd-party websites, so I figured this might be one of the reasons why.  The basic shares outstanding are reported in every 10-K/10-Q, but I'm not sure where to look for the fully diluted shares outstanding...  They might be in the 10-K/10-Q, but I don't know where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the fully diluted shares by comparing EPS vs diluted (adjusted) EPS as reported in 10K. I don't believe they report the number directly, but it is a trivial math exercise to reach it. The do report outstanding common stock (basis for EPS).